# Почему записи из БД не выносятся в ячейках таблицы?

Tags: php

Создал таблицу 4х5. Выношу кодом

```
<tr>
    <td class="table_style"> <?php echo $myrow['title'];  ?> </td>
    <td class="table_style"><?php echo $myrow['title'];  ?></td>
    <td class="table_style"><?php echo $myrow['title'];  ?></td>
    <td class="table_style"><?php echo $myrow['title'];  ?>;</td>
</tr>
```

Почему выносится вот так: ТекстТекстТекстТекст. А я хочу чтобы в начале каждого столбца выводилось.

[image]

Почему выводится не в том месте, как на картинке?

Должно вот так: Текст <-->(220px)<--> Текст <-->(220px)

Вот что выводит:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

На показанной Вами картинке не совсем понятно, что Вы имеете ввиду...
Если предполагается, что это заголовки столбцов то можете попробовать использовать элементы таблицы **thead**

<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td> ... </td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot> ... </tfoot>
 <tbody> ... </tbody>
</table>

Comment: хочу вот так чтобы было: Текст <-->(220px)<--> Текст <-->(220px)

Comment: попробуйте обернуть Ваш выводимый текст в какой-то тег в span например со своим классом в стилевой таблице, а в этом классе укажите правила позиционирования...

Comment: надо внимательно посмотреть на всю структуру страницы и стилей... возможно где-то идет перекрытие свойств...

Comment: как вариант http://jsfiddle.net/nE7Wg/

Answer (score 0):

Дай погадаю, у тебя текст выравнивается по вертикали?

Допиши либо в тег `td: valign="top"`, либо в стиль `table_style: vertical-align: top`

---

Аа, значит тебе нужно выставить ширину ячейки!

Тогда вот: либо в тег `td: width="220"`, либо в стиль `table_style: width: 220px`

Comment: я так и сделал. У меня там 220 стоит

Comment: @navi1893 посмотри пример: http://jsfiddle.net/jZBwT/ и почитай побольше про таблицы: http://htmlweb.ru/html/table.php